# DHCP server: offer different subnet addresses for different interfaces

Tags: linux, networking, dhcp

I'm running Ubuntu 10.04 on my home router which has multiple network interfaces. I have `dhcpd` configured to provide addresses from `192.168.1.0/24` subnet on certain interface. However, I'd like to also provide addresses from `192.168.2.0/24` subnet for another interface. How can I configure `dhcpd` to do so? Or, if I use another DHCP server software, for example, `dnsmasq` - how can that be configured to do the same thing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In (I believe) `/etc/default/dhcp3-server`, add the line

`INTERFACES="eth0 eth1"`

Now in the `dhcpd.conf` configuration file, you define two different subnet and the respective options.

```
subnet 192.168.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
    option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
    option routers 192.168.1.1;
    range 192.168.1.100 192.168.1.200;
}

subnet 192.168.2.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
    option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
    option routers 192.168.2.1;
    range 192.168.2.100 192.168.2.200;

}
```

This assumes of course that one interface is addressed correctly on 192.168.1.0 and the other interface is addressed correctly on 192.168.2.0.

Comment: Damn, you beat me to it! +1. Just note that the filenames may have changed. Debian renamed `dhcp-server` to `isc-dhcp-server`, but I'm not sure how recently that happened and whether or not Ubuntu 10 includes the renamed packages.

Comment: Oh that was on the surface! But that implies that the interfaces must belong to networks they give the addresses from (which is not the problem).

Comment: @rajcoumar instead of hijacking other threads and bugging people, why don't you actually provide [the information you were asked for](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/140387/pxeboot-client-not-getting-ip-address-from-the-dhcp-server#comment227035_140387)? I am deleting your comment since it is completely inappropriate to comment on a 3 year old post requesting help with something completely different.

Comment: Where is the addressing that ties the base+netmask to a particular ethernet interface?