# isc-dhcp-server conflicting with /etc/network/interfaces - Multiple instances match the same subnet

Tags: dhcp, raspbian, network-interface, isc-dhcpd

I am running Raspbian and trying to run cmd *service isc-dhcp-server start*. 
This returns the msg

```
[FAIL] Starting ISC DHCP server: dhcpd[....] check syslog for diagnostics. ... failed!
```

my */var/sys/log* file contains

```
dhcpd: Wrote 0 leases to leases file.
dhcpd: Multiple interfaces match the same subnet: wlan0 eth0
dhcpd: Multiple interfaces match the same shared network: wlan0 eth0
dhcpd:
dhcpd: No subnet declaration for wlan1 (no IPv4 addresses).
dhcpd: ** Ignoring requests on wlan1.  If this is not what
dhcpd:    you want, please write a subnet declaration
dhcpd:    in your dhcpd.conf file for the network segment
dhcpd:    to which interface wlan1 is attached. **
dhcpd:
dhcpd:
dhcpd: Not configured to listen on any interfaces!
```

My */etc/network/interfaces* contains

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback


iface wlan1 inet static
        address 192.168.42.1
        netmask 255.255.255.0


iface eth0 inet static
        address 192.168.1.100
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 192.168.1.1

allow-hotplug wlan0

iface wlan0 inet static
        address 192.168.1.200
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 192.168.1.1

wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
iface default inet dhcp

up iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.ipv4.nat
```

Breaking down the error log

**Multiple interfaces match the same subnet: wlan0 eth0**

Is subnet labelled as **address** inside the */etc/network/interfaces* file?
If so, *eth0* has *address 192.168.1.100* and *wlan0* has *address 192.168.1.200*. These are different.

Furthermore. When I rearrange my */etc/network/interfaces* file and order the blocks as the following

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface eth0 inet static
        address 192.168.1.100
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 192.168.1.1

allow-hotplug wlan0

iface wlan0 inet static
        address 192.168.1.200
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 192.168.1.1

wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

iface default inet dhcp

iface wlan1 inet static
        address 192.168.42.1
        netmask 255.255.255.0

up iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.ipv4.nat
```

The error in my *var/sys/log* file changes to only

```
dhcpd: Wrote 0 leases to leases file.
dhcpd: No subnet declaration for wlan1 (no IPv4 addresses).
dhcpd: ** Ignoring requests on wlan1.  If this is not what
...
```

Why does the previous**    dhcpd: Multiple interfaces match the same subnet: wlan0 eth0** disappear just because of the ordering of this file? if they match the same subnet then they should always match regardless of declaration right?

Comment: You realise you're trying to run the DHCP _server_, and not the client? Please post the server configuration file in your question. It's likely you've got the same subnet assigned to both interfaces.

Comment: have u check > ip a s if you get to IP addresses on the same interface the problem is that you have two dhcp client working one ontop of each other... have a look [here](http://superuser.com/questions/985082/is-there-a-way-to-disable-the-dhcp-client-in-raspbian-linux-on-a-rasperry-pi)

Answer (score 1):

The subnets for `eth0` and `wlan0` both have the same subnet/network address.

The subnet address (a.k.a. the network address) for `eth0` in interfaces is `192.168.1` (a.k.a `192.168.1.0`). It is determined by taking the "logical and" of the "address" and the "netmask". The "address" is `192.168.1.100` and the "netmask" is `255.255.255.0`.

In decimal notation the value of digit locations are ... 10000,1000,100,10,1.

In binary notation the values are ... 128, 64, 32, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1.

```
                           128 64 32 16 8 4 2 1 
 Since 192=128+64  it is     1  1  0  0 0 0 0 0  or 11000000  in binary.
 Since 168=128+32+8 it is    1  0  1  0 1 0 0 0  or 10101000  in binary.
 Since 1=1  it is            0  0  0  0 0 0 0 1  or 00000001  in binary.
 Since 100=64+32+4  it is    0  1  1  0 0 1 0 0  or 01100100  in binary.
 Since 200=128+64+8 it is    1  1  0  0 1 0 0 0  or 11001000  in binary.
 255=128+64+32+16+8+4+2+1 or 1  1  1  1 1 1 1 1  or 11111111  in binary.
```

To find the subnet or network address we must do a "logical and" of the
"address" and the "netmask". The "logical and" of 0 and 0 = 0, 1 and 0 = 0,
0 and 1 = 0, and finally 1 and 1 = 1.
Therefore `192.168.1.100`  logical and `255.255.255.0` is

```
                  11000000.10101000.00000001.01100100
 "logical and"    11111111.11111111.11111111.00000000  gives
                  11000000.10101000.00000001.00000000 which equals
                       192.     168.       1.       0  or 192.168.1.0
```

Likewise `192.168.1.200`  logical and `255.255.255.0` is

```
                  11000000.10101000.00000001.11001000
 "logical and"    11111111.11111111.11111111.00000000  gives
                  11000000.10101000.00000001.00000000 which equals
                       192.     168.       1.       0  or 192.168.1.0
```

Thus the two subnets have the same address and are therefore the same subnet.

The fix is to change `192.168.1.200` to `192.168.2.200` or to change `192.168.1.100` to `192.168.2.100`.

For a related example see [DHCP server: offer different subnet addresses for different interfaces](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37737/dhcp-server-offer-different-subnet-addresses-for-different-interfaces?rq=1)